# keyword search does not apply boolean logic correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Does the job's keyword search apply boolean logic?

Meaning can I do something like [c#] and [vb.net] to find jobs that have both tags?

If so it doesn't appear to be working correctly, this combination  yields jobs that don't match this criteria:

[image]

Comment: Not yet, but in about 30 mins I'll be switching that feature on for good...

Comment: @DeanWard - I think that makes sense as a lot of people are looking for jobs that meet certain criteria, for example, a front end developer may only be looking for a job that deals with both jquery and mvc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just pushed a build that removes the A/B test we were running for this and enables it for everybody. We're just creating the help page  documenting the available operators but, in the meantime, it works largely the same as Q&A search: tags, negation, logical binary operators.

You can search by title using the `title:` modifier, company using the `company:` modifier and filter by job type using the `type:` operator.

The help page should be linked from the jobs tab at some point tomorrow.